# How can I synchronize threads within warp in conditional while statement in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

Let's assume that we have following codes:

```
while (condition) {
  ...

  for (uint32_t gap = x >> 1; gap > 0; gap >>= 1) {
    val += __shfl_down_sync(mask, val, gap);
  }

  if (warpLane == 0)
    atomicAdd(&global_memory[threadIdx.x], val);

  ...
}
```

In this scenario, if threads in the warp enter the while loop as the following sequence:

all 32 threads, all 32 threads, only 16 threads.

how can I get thread mask that participates in while loop statements?

Below code may cause undefined behavior according to the guide described in https://devblogs.nvidia.com/using-cuda-warp-level-primitives:

```
while (condition) {
  uint32_t active = __activemask();
  for (uint32_t gap = x >> 1; gap > 0; gap >>= 1) {
    val += __shfl_down_sync(active, val, gap);
  }

  if (warpLane == 0)
    atomicAdd(&global_memory[threadIdx.x], val);

  ...
}
```

According to the guide, __activemask() might not generate mask as I expected.

Below also causes undefined behavior according to the above guide:

```
while (condition) {
  uint32_t active = __activemask();
  for (uint32_t gap = x >> 1; gap > 0; gap >>= 1) {
    val += __shfl_down_sync(active, val, gap);
  }

  if (warpLane == 0)
    atomicAdd(&global_memory[threadIdx.x], val);

  ...
  __warpsync(active);
}
```

Then, how I can get mask correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cooperative groups](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cooperative-groups/) like:

```
#include <cooperative_groups.h>
namespace cg = cooperative_groups;

while (condition) { 
...
auto active = cg::coalesced_threads(); // this line can be moved out of while if the condition does not cause thread divergence

 for (uint32_t gap = x >> 1; gap > 0; gap >>= 1) { 
        //val += __shfl_down_sync(mask, val, gap);
        val += active.shfl_down(val, gap);
 }
 if (warpLane == 0)
    atomicAdd(&global_memory[threadIdx.x], val); 

... 
}
```

If you want to generate the mask yourself and do old fashioned you can use:

```
uint32_t FullMask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
uint32_t mask =  __ballot_sync(FullMask, someCondition);
```

However if you had further branching in your code you have to always keep track of the `mask` before branching and use it instead of `FullMask` in the `ballot`. So the second update before branch will be:

```
uint32_t newMask =  __ballot_sync(mask, someNewCondition);
```

Comment: Does coalesced_threads() in while loop guarantee synchronization in collecting active?

Comment: @sungjuncho it depends on the architecture. The group (active) is synchronized in all. Threads which are not in the group are not synchronized in >Volta arch

Comment: @sungjuncho if you want to synchronize the entire warp you have to force everyone to enter the while loop and keep the ones that are out idle

Comment: do u mean that all threads calling coalesced_threads()  synchronize at the moment of calling this function? (I don't care other threads that do not call this function) The reason why im asking it is that I do not want behavior like activemask() that is, active threads might cause unexpected mask since they can call activemask() at different time.